# Scheme: the procedure is recursive, but is the process recursive or iterative?

Tags: recursion, scheme, lisp, r5rs

so I'm not sure if I finally understood it or maybe I'm still wrong. Is it correct that:

```
(define (add-one x)
  (+ x 1))

(define (sub-one x)
  (- x 1))

(define (add-numbers x y)
  (if (zero? y)
          x
          (add-numbers (add-one x) (sub-one y))))
```

... *add-numbers* is a recursive procedure and a recursive process and...

```
(define (add-numbers2 x y)
  (if (zero? y)
          x
          (add-numbers2 (+ x 1) (- y 1))))
```

... *add-numbers2* is a recursive procedure and an iterative process?

Answer (score 1):

Both are recursive *syntactically*, but both generate iterative computational processes.  In the first function:

```
(define (add-numbers x y)
  (if (zero? y)
          x
          (add-numbers (add-one x) (sub-one y))))
```

Then, if `y` is not zero, what happens is that the thing needs to evaluate `(add-numbers (add-one x) (sub-one y))`, and to do this it needs to call `(add-one x)` and `(add-one y)`, and then call `add-numbers` on the two results, with the result of the whole function being whatever this call to `add-numbers` returns.  The important thing is that the call to `add-numbers` is the very *last* thing that happens.  There's no need to return back to the point when that function call was made, as there's nothing more to do except return the calculated value.  This means the process is iterative.

In the second version:

```
(define (add-numbers2 x y)
  (if (zero? y)
          x
          (add-numbers2 (+ x 1) (- y 1))))
```

Well, the easy way to see that this is the same is to realize that `+` and `-` are *just functions*, so this is exactly the same thing!  The only difference is that `+` and `-` happen to be functions defined by the implementation, rather than by you.

Here is a version which really describes a *recursive* computational process:

```
(define (add-numbers3 x y)
  (if (zero? y)
      x
      (+ 1 (add-numbers3 x (- y 1)))))
```

In this version, if `y` is not zero then the function has to call itself on `x` and the result of subtracting 1 from `y` ... and *then*, once it's done that, it still needs to add 1 to the result of that call.  So it needs to keep a memory that *there is this pending operation* of adding 1, and then actually do that addition when it returns from that function call.  It's perhaps easier to see this using your original functions:

```
(define (add-numbers4 x y)
  (if (zero? y)
      x
      (add-one (add-numbers4 x (sub-one y)))))
```

Now you can clearly see that when the recursive call to `add-numbers4` returns there is still more work to do.

Comment: I would say they are both recursive calls, but the first one is _tail-recursive_, which means it can be executed without needing the stack to grow. But the function call is still recursive.

Comment: @OliverMason: both of OP's examples are tail-recursive, which is why they both generate iterative processes (not calls).  My final example is not tail recursive and thus generates a recursive process.

Answer (score 0):

@tb explains both processes are iterative, and that is correct. We can visualise the process as -

```
(add-numbers 3 5)
(add-numbers 4 4)
(add-numbers 5 3)
(add-numbers 6 2)
(add-numbers 7 1)
(add-numbers 8 0)
8
```

See how it stays nice and flat? That is a *linear* process. And with a tiny modification, we can spawn an entirely different process -

```
(define (add-numbers x y)
  (if (zero? y)
      x
      (+ 1 (add-numbers x (- y 1))))
```

Notice how the process deepens as dependent values are computed, until it finally collapses to a return value. This is a *recursive* process -

```
(add-numbers 3 5)
(+ 1 (add-numbers 3 4))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (add-numbers 3 3)))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (add-numbers 3 2))))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (add-numbers 3 1)))))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (add-numbers 3 0))))))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 3)))))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 4))))
(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 5)))
(+ 1 (+ 1 6))
(+ 1 7)
8
```

Comment: wups, just left some of the draft text in place :D